# Converting an "ASCII decimal" to an integer in C

Tags: c, integer, ascii

I am trying to convert an "ASCII decimal" to an integer. The "ASCII decimal" can be up to 10 digits long and is padded with spaces if there are no more digits (ie `36________`, where the "_" is actually space). I am really new to C (I just started learning last week) and I have absolutely no clue how to do so.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fda = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    char arSize[10];
    read(fd, arSize, 10);
    //convert arSize to an int and store in i
    lseek(archive, i, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Why did it fail? Please show us your first trial, even if unsuccessful - it will help us guide you to the solution, and let you learn in the process. If you are having troubles with c - try to describe how you think it can be done in words/pseudo code, and we'll be able to help you translate it to C. You should also mention if it is homework - you will probably get more explaining answers (rather then a simple library function call, if it is the case)

Comment: You can just use `atoi`.  Unless you want your own function, which you'll find 1000's of examples (usually from interview questions) with a quick google search

Comment: ... I haven't tried anything because I don't know C and have no clue where to start. I have tried searching all over the internet and have come up with nothing. Also, I did show you what I am trying to do with pseudo code in the comment I just don't know where to go from there. I would also like to mention that is is kind of part of a homework assignment but the assignment is not about converting to an int, it is about working with system calls. I just transferred to a new school that uses a different language (C) than my old school (Java) so I am assuming that most students already know how.

Comment: Thank you peacemaker for actually being helpful, that was all I needed.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) or [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/).

Since you seem to be opening a file, you may also find [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) helpful.